# Is it possible to send form data to server from developer tools

Tags: security, authentication, frontend, developer-tools

I just learnt one can manipulate the frontend code of a website from the developer tools that comes with some browsers. Now, my question is that if someone can manipulate my js, HTML and CSS codes to suitable needs, and was able to send a request to my webserver, will the server receive and process the request as authenticated request. Let me site a suitable example:

Let's say I created a form that uses ajax to retrieve some information from my webserver, in the form I have a hidden input that contains numbers which determine the information that will be displayed (e.g. 1 should display information for level 1 users, 2 should display information for level 2 users). The default value of the hidden input is 1, now if the user (level 1) is able to tweak the frontend code and set the value to 2 before sending, will he receive the information meant for level 2.

If this is possible, how can I prevent such thing from happening, or what is the standard procedure for handling situations like this?

Answer (score 1):

The typical rules in this case are:

1. Validate
2. Validate
3. Validate

Do not trust the client exclusively to tell you whether they have the permission or not.  You should have the information to determine that on the server side, use it.
Validate client side requests, and make sure the user that is requesting an action has the actually has permissions to do so, and that the data they are sending is valid.
Sure, you can have client side validation for a good UX experience, but always backstop it with server side validation, authentication and authorization.

The best way to prevent your example scenario is: Don't send the client side data they aren't supposed to see and then rely on the client to hide it.  If the user isn't supposed to see it, *don't send it*.